# Swapping values within same table with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a really weird situation. I need to swap a column value between two rows in the same table so I use (where **s1** and **s2** are the two rows)

```
UPDATE table s1, table s2 
SET s1.data = s2.data, s2.data = @temp
WHERE @temp:=s1.data AND [some expression that works]
ORDER BY s2.data ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This generates an error **Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY**

I just want to find the entry from the table that have the closest smaller **data** entry to the original entry and swap the two values. Doing

```
SELECT * FROM table s1, table s2
WHERE [the same expression that works]
ORDER BY s2.data ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Returns a table with the required results, but the mentioned **UPDATE** does not work. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I believe if you can only use `ORDER BY` if and only if you are modifying only the table to which the column(s) in your `ORDER BY` belong to. I know you are actually modifying only one table, but MySQL might not see it that way.

Comment: Also why do you have the `LIMIT 1` clause? Aren't you modifying at least 2 rows?

Comment: I just tried adding **s1.order ASC** after the first **order by** with no success. Again the same error occurs...

Comment: pretty sure you're missing a join condition, and order by is really not appropriate for this.  what is your primary key for both tables?

Comment: And even by putting **LIMIT 2** it does give the same error :( Well, I'm actually modifying one row of the resulting table after the join that the **WHERE** will do, but the source of that table are two different rows.

Comment: As I suspected, you can't use `ORDER BY` here: "You can also perform `UPDATE` operations covering multiple tables. However, you cannot use `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` with a multiple-table `UPDATE`. "

Comment: The tables are the same and the key is just an id.

Comment: That sux... So probably I'll use several queries and PHP... Thought I was making things simpler instead it got quite complicated :D

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Provide tables with data, before and after your wanted operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what I want cannot be done in one *MySQL* query. I ended up doing 3 queries, one **SELECT** and two **UPDATE** for each of the columns and using temporary variables in *PHP*. I guess it can be also done in three consecutive queries in *MySQL* with *MySQL* temporary variables.